# Java - How to highlight searched word in results

Tags: java, jframe

This is searching it but i can't get it to highlight the searched word in the results it is supposed to highlight it in yellow the searched word in the results pane

here is what is supposed to do

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldFmd.png)

Highlight What was searched in results pane

Thank You

Here is the Code : /

```
package search.text.file;

  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JList;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.UIManager;
  import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class SearchTextFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SearchTextFile();
}

public SearchTextFile() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException |     IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bible Search");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField findText;
    private JButton search;
    private DefaultListModel<String> model;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        findText = new JTextField(20);
        searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        search = new JButton("Search");
        searchPane.add(search, gbc);

        add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        model = new DefaultListModel<>();
        JList list = new JList(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(list));

        ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

        search.addActionListener(handler);
        findText.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.removeAllElements();
//                    BufferedReader reader = null;

            String searchText = findText.getText();
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     FileReader(new File("bible.txt")))) {

                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    if (text.contains(searchText)) {

                        model.addElement(text);

                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException exp) {

                exp.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Something Went Wrong", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
          }
       }
}
}
```

Comment: It takes some time formulate an answer, it's not the simplest thing in the world, not hard, just needs some thinking, hang in there, we'll get to you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer). This will allow you to customise the way each cell in the `JList`

In your case, it's a little more difficult, as you want to highlight the word (in yellow), so you need to do some extra work to wrap the word in `<html><font>` tags

Something like...

```
public class HighlightListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof String && searchPhrase != null) {
            String text = (String) value;
            if (text.contains(searchPhrase)) {
                text = text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
                value = "<html>" + text.replace(searchPhrase, "<font color=#ffff00>" + searchPhrase + "</font>") + "</html>";
            }
        }
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

In my example `HighlightListCellRenderer` is an inner class to `TestPane` and this allows it to access the `searchPhrase` field I added.

[image: Highlighted]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SearchTextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SearchTextFile();
    }

    public SearchTextFile() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bible Search");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField findText;
        private JButton search;
        private DefaultListModel<String> model;
        private JList list;

        private String searchPhrase;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            findText = new JTextField(20);
            searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            search = new JButton("Search");
            searchPane.add(search, gbc);

            add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            model = new DefaultListModel<>();
            list = new JList(model);
            list.setCellRenderer(new HighlightListCellRenderer());
            add(new JScrollPane(list));

            ActionHandler handler = new ActionHandler();

            search.addActionListener(handler);
            findText.addActionListener(handler);

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Script.txt")))) {

                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    model.addElement(text);
                }

            } catch (IOException exp) {

                exp.printStackTrace();

            }
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                searchPhrase = findText.getText();
                if (searchPhrase != null && searchPhrase.trim().length() == 0) {
                    searchPhrase = null;
                }
                list.repaint();
//              model.removeAllElements();
////                    BufferedReader reader = null;
//
//              String searchText = findText.getText();
//              try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("bible.txt")))) {
//
//                  String text = null;
//                  while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
//
//                      if (text.contains(searchText)) {
//
//                          model.addElement(text);
//
//                      }
//
//                  }
//
//              } catch (IOException exp) {
//
//                  exp.printStackTrace();
//                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Something Went Wrong", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
//
//              }
            }
        }

        public class HighlightListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

            public final String WITH_DELIMITER = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                if (value instanceof String && searchPhrase != null) {
                    String text = (String) value;
                    if (text.contains(searchPhrase)) {
                        text = text.replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
                        value = "<html>" + text.replace(searchPhrase, "<font color=#ffff00>" + searchPhrase + "</font>") + "</html>";
                    }
                }
                return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If you want highlight the text's background (in yellow), you could use something like...

```
value = "<html>" + text.replace(searchPhrase, "<span STYLE='background-color: #ffff00'>" + searchPhrase + "</span>") + "</html>";
```

instead

Comment: Nice. didn't know about cell renderer.

Comment: but where is it getting the variable in all the classes ActionHandler, HighlightListCellRenderer

Comment: `searchPhrase` is an instance field of `TestPane`, because `ActionHandler` and `HighlightListCellRenderer ` are inner, instance classes of `TestPane`, they have access to all the instance fields of `TestPane`

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a `JTextPane` to display the text and do the highlighting. That is text is typically displayed in a text component.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextAndNewLinesTest extends JFrame
{
    public TextAndNewLinesTest()
        throws Exception
    {
        String text =
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n" +
            "one two three four five\r\n";

        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setText(text);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textPane );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.CYAN);

        String search = "three";
        int offset = 0;

        int length = textPane.getDocument().getLength();
        text = textPane.getDocument().getText(0, length);

        while ((offset = text.indexOf(search, offset)) != -1)
        {
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(offset, search.length(), keyWord, false); 
            offset += search.length();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new TextAndNewLinesTest();
        frame.setTitle("Text and New Lines");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(400, 120);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Also, when using a JTextPane, you can just use the `read(...)` method to load the data into the text pane.

When you build your search function you would use the following to clear the attributes before starting the search:

```
doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), new SimpleAttributeSet(), true);
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought that to

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class MySearch02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MySearch02();
}

public MySearch02() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField findText;
        private JTextArea ta;
        private Timer keyTimer;

        public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel searchPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        searchPane.add(new JLabel("Find: "), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        findText = new JTextField(20);
        searchPane.add(findText, gbc);

        add(searchPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(ta));

        loadFile();

        keyTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String find = findText.getText();
                Document document = ta.getDocument();
                try {
                    for (int index = 0; index + find.length() < document.getLength(); index++) {
                        String match = document.getText(index, find.length());
                        if (find.equals(match)) {
                                javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter =
                                    new     javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
                            ta.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, index +     find.length(),
                                    highlightPainter);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        keyTimer.setRepeats(false);

        findText.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                keyTimer.restart();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                keyTimer.restart();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                keyTimer.restart();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void loadFile() {
        String searchText = findText.getText();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("search.txt")))) {
            ta.read(reader, "Text");
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Could not create file", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        ta.setCaretPosition(0);
    }
}
}
```